# Does Polymer fire() publish the event globally?

Tags: javascript, events, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Suppose the following is called from within a Polymer element:

`this.fire("reset-counters");`.

Will the `reset-counters` event be published to all elements that listen for that event or is in heard within the element that called `this.fire()` only?

Comment: to all listeners added, like standard custom events.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `this.fire()` raises a bubbling even which will be handled by all elements up the DOM tree. Like most events in the browser.

Polymer does however offer an API similar to the [native events API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), The `fire` method takes three parameters: **event name**, **details** object and **options** object. In **options**, set `bubbles: false` to forbid the event from being pushed up the DOM tree.

See the example below to see how only the immediate listener fires when you click the second button.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'my-elem',
  bubbling: function() {
    this.fire('my-event', 'bubbling');
  },
  nonbubbling: function() {
    this.fire('my-event', 'nonbubbling', {
      bubbles: false
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import"/>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <my-elem></my-elem>
  </div>
  
  <dom-module id="my-elem">
    <template>
      <input type="button" value="fire bubbling" on-tap="bubbling" />
      <input type="button" value="fire non-bubbling" on-tap="nonbubbling" />
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <script>
    document.querySelector('my-elem')
      .addEventListener('my-event', handle('my-elem'));
    
    document.querySelector('div')
      .addEventListener('my-event', handle('div'));
    
    document
      .addEventListener('my-event', handle('document'));
    
    function handle(elem) {
      return function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail + ' handled on ' + elem);
      };
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow - I'm really impressed the answer running code snippets included - thanks.  Great answer - makes a lot of sense.  Just a heads up - when I click the run button I get "ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined".